# How to handle a menu in angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, dom, menu

I would like to set the class active and run a function when the user click on one option.
I try to convert my JQuery code into angular2, Jquery code was as follows:

```
function setOption (segmented, option) {
    $(segmented+" span").removeClass("selected");
    const o = $(option);
    const u = $(segmented+">.underline");
    o.addClass("selected");
    o.css("animation","bounce 0.35");

    const p = o.position();
    const left = p.left+(o.width()-u.width())/2;
    const ttop = p.top+o.height()+10;

    //console.log("underline left="+left+"px,\ttop= "+ttop+"px\tw="+o.width()+"px");
    u.css({"top": ttop+"px", "left": left+"px"});
}
```

This function merely set the class to the right option and move the absolute positioned div.underline beneath the active option.

On angular2, my HTML fragment is as follows:

```
<nav #topMenu id="topMenu" class="ALADDIN-SegmentedControl" style="width: 460px">
    <a #menuOption routerLink="/dashboard" (click)="setOption('#topMenu', this)" class="menuOption active">Dashboard</a>
    <a #menuOption routerLink="/team" (click)="setOption('#topMenu', this)" class="menuOption">Équipe</a>
    <a #menuOption routerLink="/projects" (click)="setOption('#topMenu', this)" class="menuOption">Projets</a>
    <div #underline class="underline"></div>
</nav>
```

My component is as follows:

```
import {ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@ViewChild('menuOption') menuOption: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('underline') underline: ElementRef;

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls:  ['app/app.component.css'],
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setOption('#topMenu', "#topMenu>a:first-child");
    }

    setOption (segmented: string, option: string) {

        console.log("menuOption="+JSON.stringify(menuOption));
        /*
        menuOption.map(
            function(d){d.nativeElement.removeClass("active")
        );
        */
    }
}
```

I missed something, I cannot capture menuOption elements as an array.
I really don't understand how to translate my former code into angular2.

Comment: Is using an UI third library is an option for you? Because Angular Material 2 provides a nice implementation of a context menu. (See: https://material.angular.io/components/component/menu)

Comment: Well, in the future and if I can adapt the visual to my design. But currently, I need to make my own code work @MaximeGélinas

Answer (score 1):

### Handle active links with Angular.

The [`routerLinkActive`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) directive will set the active class automatically when the URL is the same as the one provided to the [`routerLink`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) directive.

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/dashboard" 
       routerLinkActive="active" 
       (click)="someFunction()">
        Dashboard
    </a>
    <a routerLink="/projects" 
       routerLinkActive="active" 
       (click)="someFunction()">
        Projects
    </a>
</nav>
```

For the other part you can use the [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) directive to apply classes to an element.

### Change an element style with Angular.

Instead of getting an element and apply styles on it like we have to do with JQuery, with Angular we have to declare styles and then apply them to the element.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-nav',
    template: `
        <nav>
            <a>...</a>
            <a>...</a>
            /* We apply the styles. */
            <div class="underline" 
                 [style.top]="underlineTop" 
                 [style.left]="underlineLeft">
            </div>
        </nav>
    `
})
export class MyNavComponent {
     /* We declare the styles. */
     underlineTop = '0px';
     underlineLeft = '0px';

     changeUnderlinePosition(x, y) {
         /* Change the position here... eg: */
         underlineTop =  x + 'px';
         underlineLeft = y + 'px';
     }
}
```

> In a real world context the position logic should probably be encapsulated in a directive.

### Note

> Angular use a very different way than JQuery to do stuff so the code
>   can't really be converted.

If my answer does not satisfy you. Please tell me and I will work on it.

Comment: Thanks @Maxime Gélinas but it does not answer the question as I need to catch one html éléments (underline) and change its position.